# DNS entries required for a domain

Tags: dns, centos, plesk

My OS is CentOS 6.7 with Plesk 12.5.x

There are always some errors when I am checking DNS records in any DNS diagnostic tool. Can anybody please advise what records are necessary to set for all domains?

Here is my Plesk=>Tools & Settings => DNS Template
[image]

Here is error screen shot:

[image]

Another domain throwing the following error:
[image]
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Sorry to post this question here. I request to admin to please move this question to serverfault if this is not related here

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: @user3788685 I added errors screen shot in my question

Comment: someone is giving -1 to each of my question. Why? how can I see who down rated?

Comment: No you can't see who it was who down voted. Your error message looks like you have a wrong NS set on the domain compared to what you have configured.  For any more help from me I'd need to know the real domain so I can test from something that's not a web control panel - it looks like you removed the doamin from the 1st pic.

Comment: @user3788685 the real domain name is w e l l n e s s b d . c o m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first major problem I see with your domain is that two of the nameservers listed do not reply.

`ns1.onlinenics.net.` `ns1.wellnessbd.com.` Maybe they are firewalled ?

And looking at the whois record it shows these as the registered nameservers;

`NSSEC.ONLINE.NET` `NS1.ONLINENICS.NET`

I'd check that first - it may just be a config error, or there may be a firewall/IPtables in the way blocking the query.

to fix the spf record you need something like this in your zone with the addresses of your valid sender(s);
`"v=spf1 mx ip4:<ips of valid senders>/<cidr> -all"`

If you have a way to export your zone file that would be a help and much easier to read and provide corrections too, sadly I'm no use with control panel type affairs.

I found a better online web tool which tests your dns. Specific results for your domain are [here](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=wellnessbd.com&timestamp=1468077966&view=2)

Comment: I deleted one extra name server and its seems working but now its throwing only one error `dns - At least one name server failed to respond in a timely manner` Please check it [This link](http://mxtoolbox.com/domain/wellnessbd.com/)

Comment: ive updated the answer with a link to a better online tester results for your domain. The server `62.210.92.202` which is presumably your hosting co. is not answering to dns requests. It's not your issue as such but you could/should raise a ticket with there support or move to a different server (if you have that option)

Comment: The hosting company replied to make sure udp and tcp port 53 is open. I have checked in ping.eu and port 53 is open for all domains. I added in ticket and from yesterday they not updated this ticket

Comment: I tested it and its working for me; `202.92.210.62.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer centos.gsw1.com.` `centos.gsw1.com has address 62.210.92.202` That error would normally mean you have set a reverse dns mane for something that has no forward dns name.

Comment: no i can't access it either. Sorry I cant help with iptables stuff. Looks like port 80 is closed  - i cant access it from anywhere. easy test is to switch off iptables and see if you can connect

Comment: Thanks for your favorable replies. I recreated resolv.conf file and now everything is working fine